# Creating Athena table with escape character before separator

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena, hive-serde

I am creating table in Athena from data in s3. Here is short version of what query looks like.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tablename`(
  `licensee_pub` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `admin_number` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `account_name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `ipi_number` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `title` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `play_minutes` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `play_seconds` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'path/to/s3'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

files in S3 is comma separated and though table is created fine but there is issues with few lines having record lines like below in file

`"a","b","c","d","abc ///def\\\","e","21","32"`

Instances of line where "abc ///def\\" is not created properly, putting all data coming after this in one (title) field only like

`abc ///def\",e,21,32`

Probable escaping and not identifying column correctly.

Is there any way to have an exception for a text like def\\ to not escape, or any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The `escapeChar` property in your DDL says the escape char is a single `\` (backslashes in `escapeChar` need to be escaped, so two backslashes really means one).

This means that when the serde encounters `"\\\"` it will consume the first backslash as an escape for the second, and the third as escape for the `"`. Since the end quote is escaped the serde will continue reading until the next (unescaped) quote.

If you don't have actual escaped quotes you can just change the `escapeChar` to something else, and then decide in your application what `\\\` means.

Comment: unfortunately I have actual escaped quotes in my string. I need to escape other characters with \ but the one in the end of string.

Comment: I don't think you can solve that problem. Either `\"` means an escaped quote or it doesn't, you can't express that it only means escape in some contexts.